# Android data share conflict in Application class

Tags: android, multithreading, conflict

```
public class ApplicationCore extends Application {
  private boolean isShow = true;
  public void setShow(boolean show) {
    isShow = show;
  }


  class AppStatusThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      super.run();
      try{
        while (true) {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          Log.d("show","show?->" + isShow);
         }
       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
  }
}


public class MainActivity {
  public void onFragmentChange(int index) {
    ((ApplicationCore)getApplicationContext()).setShow(index==0);
  }
}
```

Like above, in Android application class, I defined a variable `show`, and I use it in MainActivity. The problem is, when I use a **Thread** in Application and I change the 'show' value to false, the `PushService`(Push SDK) will log the 'show' value as not changing.

```
07-23 00:43:12.199 4523-4523/com.xxx.xxx : show?->false 
07-23 00:43:12.351 4559-4585/com.xxx.xxx:xg_service_v2 : show?->true
07-23 00:43:13.199 4523-4523/com.xxx.xxx : show?->false
07-23 00:43:13.351 4559-4585/com.xxx.xxx:xg_service_v2 : show?->true
07-23 00:43:14.199 4523-4523/com.xxx.xxx : show?->false
07-23 00:43:14.351 4559-4585/com.xxx.xxx:xg_service_v2 : show?->true
```

I don't understand why `show` would be duplicated.

Comment: can you explain where 'com.xxx.xxx:xg_service_v2 : show?->true' come from?